# What is the explanation for this anomaly in my Heroku dashboard?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, memory

The image below is a screenshot from my Heroku metrics dashboard. As you can see, at 12pm my 'max swap' abruptly fell to zero. This coincided with a corresponding spike in my 'max RSS'. What do these figures represent, and what are the implications for my app?

For what it's worth, the app seems to be functioning fine. There has been no significant change in its response time, throughput or dyno load.

[image]